# Prefix post date

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to display post dates with the prefix 'Posted on'. I'm guessing this is fairly straightforward but am having trouble finding answers that don't relate to WP database security. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: This would be better asked on [wordpress.se].

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please note that [you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting]. If you have a [specific question about your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it should include a summary of what your attempts so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) function. For instance,
     Posted On  
This would output Posted on 18 Aug 2017 or whatever date format you set for your WP installation.